# How can i show left shift operator on my button in android?

Tags: android

I tried using this code but it's showing an error "Tag Name Expected".I don't want to use an image to show that in background of button i wan't to use the symbol ">>" itself.

```
XML code:-
 <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="@string/leftshi"
        android:id="@+id/leftshi"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        />
String values:
 <resources>
        <string name="leftshi">"<<"</string> //Error is shown here.
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in resources are written **without quotes**, also special characters should be either escaped or written in `&` code:

```
<string name="leftshi">&lt;&lt;</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use the escape symbol...try escapse symbol for xml.

[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Answer (score 1):

In XML you should use &lt; to include a less-than sign in character data.